# Long processing; way to periodically send a 102 Processing response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, proxy, http-status-codes

I have a Rails app that can take a long time to prepare its response to some queries.  (Mostly the delay is rendering the dataset into JSON or YAML.)  The app sits behind a proxy whose configuration I cannot alter, with the result that these long-running queries tend to get terminated by the proxy as timeouts.  Chunking doesn't help because there's nothing to chunk until the render is fully complete.

Is there any supported or already existing way in Rails to set up an asynchronous repeating task that could send back `102 Processing` responses to keep the proxy happy until the complete response is ready?

I would **really** prefer not to have to implement pagination semantics.

I have control over the app and the client; both bits are my code.  I *don't* have control over the proxy, nor the app's server.

Any suggestions are really welcome!

Comment: Did you have a look at [Rails Streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html)? It does not support JSON or XML, but perhaps inspires you in some way. Beside that I think this sounds like a problem that might benefit from background jobs and caching.

Comment: No, I haven't.  I'll take a look at that.  Right now I'm noodling with `EventMachine` and some middelware.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would likely solve the problem by POSTing the initial request and having the rails app return the appropriate HTTP status code. Then I'd have javascript on the client side that would poll the server at reasonable intervals for the status of the render. The status action could return the 102 response until the processing is complete. Then you could insert a link into the page with the javascript that the user could click to download the finished file.